# Can I lock a record from a join SQL statement using ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK?

Tags: sql, rowlocking

I have a stored procedure to get the data I want:

```
SELECT  a.SONum, a.Seq1, a.SptNum, a.Qty1, a.SalUniPriP, a.PayNum, a.InvNum, 
    a.BLNum, c.ETD, c.ShpNum,  f.IssBan
FROM OrdD a JOIN OrdH b ON a.SONum = b.SONum  
    LEFT JOIN Invh c ON a.InvNum = c.InvNum 
    LEFT JOIN cus d ON b.CusCod = d.CusCod  
    LEFT JOIN BL e ON a.BLNum = e.BLNum
    LEFT JOIN PayMasH f ON f.PayNum = a.PayNum
    LEFT JOIN Shipment g ON g.ShpNum = c.ShpNum  
WHERE b.CusCod IN (SELECT CusCod FROM UsrInc WHERE UseID=@UserID and UseLev=@UserLvl) 
    AND d.CusGrp = @CusGrp
```

After I get those records into cursor, I used `ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK` to lock all the related invoice numbers.

```
SELECT InvNum FROM Invh WITH (ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK) WHERE InvNum =
```

Can I issue locking on the table `INVH` at the point I select the table from a few table using join command at my store procedure?

Any advice, please!

Comment: I have 2 questions. Why are you using cursors? And which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, provided you format your SQL correctly. The general pattern you require is as follows:

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT    *
FROM      table_1 AS t1 {WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)}
JOIN      table_2 AS t2 {WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)}
ON        t1.a = t2.a

COMMIT TRAN   -- locking ends here
```

Where `{}` is optional (omit the `{}`). So lock as you put the "`WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)`" clause on each table you wish to lock, it will work.

So you can put the lock where you want it, as per your question.